# How has the second algorithm become more efficient than the first one and how is the right side of the subarray moving in the second algorithm?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, data-structures

Question - Given an array of n numbers, our task is to calculate the maximum subarray sum, i.e., the largest possible sum of a sequence of consecutive values in the
array. The problem is interesting when there may be negative values in the array. The array = {-1,2,4,-3,5,2,-5,2}.

First algorithm -

```
int best = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        for (int b = a; b < n; b++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = a; k <= b; k++) {
                sum += array[k];
            }
        best = max(best,sum);
        }
    }
cout << best << "\n";
```

Second algorithm -

```
int best = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int b = a; b < n; b++) {
            sum += array[b];
            best = max(best,sum);
        }
    }
cout << best << "\n";
```

This is what it says in the book - It is easy to make Algorithm 1 more efficient by removing one loop from it. This is possible by calculating the sum at the same time when the right end of the
subarray moves.

How is the right end of the subarray moving in the second algorithm, could someone explain it to me?

Comment: b is the right end of the subarray, the moving is the increment...

Comment: [std::partial_sum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) might help to understand too.

Comment: How is b the right end, shouldn't it be the left end because it is equal to a? @Turo

Comment: a runs from 0 to n, b runs from a to n. b  is the right end.

Comment: But it is still running from the left to the right, so how is it the right end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version does a brute force comparsion of all subarrays sums for subarrays starting at index `a` till index `b`, lets call those subarrays sums `subsum(a,b)`.

The second version is also rather brute force but uses the fact that `subsum(a,b+1) == subsum(a,b) + array[b+1]`.

In other words: To know the sum of the first say `10` elements you can use the previously calculated sum for the first `9` elements. If you would solve the problem with pen and paper this would be obvious, but the first version is not doing that. Instead the first version has two nested loops for all combinations of `a` and `b` and always starts with a fresh `sum = 0`, which is rather wasteful.

---

Consider only the outer loops of the first version:

```
for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
    for (int b = a; b < n; b++) {
        int sum = 0;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here `//...` calculates `subsum(a,b)`.

In the second version:

```
int best = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int b = a; b < n; b++) {
        sum += array[b];
        best = max(best,sum);
    }
}
```

The outer loop is responsible for starting the subarray at different "left ends". And the inner loop "moves" the "righ end".

The inner loop body calculates `subsum(a,b)` and the next iteration of the inner loop "moves" `b` to the next index to calculate `subsum(a,b)` by using the above relation: `subsum(a,b) == subsum(a,b-1) + array[b]`. Because `a` is fixed in the inner loop, the author is talking about "moving the right end".

Comment: I still didn't understand :(. How is the right end changing?

Comment: @ProgrammerGuy I have the impression that you are focusing to much on wording in the book. If you use a debugger and at the same time reproduce what the code does with pen and paper, it should become clear

Comment: I'm not able to understand why `b` is acting as the right end. Shouldn't it be the left end because it runs from a to n?

Comment: @ProgrammerGuy the right end is the last element that is added to the sum. The right end is moving in both versions. The point is just that you can calculate `subsum(a,b)` for all values of `b` by only "moving" `b`.

Comment: @ProgammerGuy in both versions both left and right end are "moving", just in a different way. As I said before, dont focus too much on wording, but look at the code (and what your debugger can tell you about it)

Comment: @ProgrammerGuy `subsum(a,b)` is the sum of all elements starting from the one at index `a` till the one at index `b`. `b` is the "right end" of the subarray

Comment: I understood how the right end moves in the first one, but I'm still not understanding how in the second one. Could you show an example flowing through the loops? I can't understand it even if I do it manually

Comment: @ProgrammerGuy your debugger can